# how to use etw nlog for writing log to custom eventsource

Tags: c#, nlog

For my console application , I want to write all the logs to custom event source under `Application and Services Logs` under separate section `MyEventSourceName`.

I tried to use `NLog.Etw`, but seems nothing appears. How to do this?

[image: g]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  autoReload="true"
  throwExceptions="false">

<extensions>
  <add assembly="NLog.Etw" />
</extensions>

<targets async="true">
  <target xsi:type="EtwEventSource"
        name="eetw"
        providerName="MyEventSourceName"
        taskName="${level}"
        layout="${message}">

   </target>
 </targets>

 <rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="eetw" />
 </rules>
```

```
class Program
{
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        logger.Info("New person created with name {0}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Details about seeing ETW-data in the EventLog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2009/09/08/part-2-exploring-and-decoding-etw-providers-using-event-log-channels/

Answer (score 3):

You could use the eventlog target:

For example:

```xml
<target xsi:type="EventLog" 
        name="eventlog" 
        source="MyEventSourceName" 
        log="MyEventSourceLogName"      
        layout ="${message}${newline}${exception:format=ToString}"/>
```

See [docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventLog-target)

The target supports .NET3.5+  and .NET Standard 2.0. For NetStandard 2.0 use the [NLog.WindowsEventLog package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.WindowsEventLog).

Comment: Please check https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Internal-logging

Comment: this is writing event, but under `Application` with source `test`. It's NOT writing under `Application and Services Logs`. This is `ETW` based

Comment: @user584018 Log-property by default "Application". Try changing it. Ex `<target xsi:type="EventLog" name="eventlog" source="MyEventSourceName" log="MyEventSourceLogName" />`

Comment: Yes. Thanks @Rolf.  What purpose ETW solve? Can console or window service logs captured as ETW?

Comment: @user584018 ETW allows you to publish tons of data without it affecting the app that publishes. It requires an external app to setup a listener for the ETW-source and only then data is captured and can be processed. Similar to DebugView https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview but with multiple source-name from the same application.